# SOLVED: S7 Edge SM-G935S Soft-bricked: Unable to mount all partitions

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

The problem is solved, the solution is posted in the answer:

Problem

- The device is unable to mount every partition, this includes:

/efs

/persdata

/system

/data

/cache

The credit goes to member greenman of sammobile forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is as followed:

Following the guide [here](https://www.sammobile.com/forum/showthread.php?t=30800) to flash the stock firmware and Repartition the device.

Here is a full write up of the Repartition process, taken straight from the Sammobile forum website by the member *greenman*. This is for in case of the website is not available.

```
"Here is how to install an S7 firmware

In the S7 firmware Samsung are now providing 5 files.

Phone preparation:
To avoid any issues with FRP (Factory Reset Protection) go to Settings > About device > build number > Tap 7 times to activate Developer options.
Now go to Developer options > OEM unlock

FRP LOCK and OEM LOCK are now both OFF.

1. Download and install Odin on your PC

    [Download Odin v3.11.1][http://dl.sammobile.com/Odin3-v3.11.1.zip]



2. Choose your FIRMWARE by putting in your phone Model version
https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares

3. Download and unzip your firmware (do not use WinRAR as it can give errors)

4. From your download put these files into Odin:

BL
AP
CP
CSC (not HOME_CSC)

5. Now look at the Odin Settings (for this select Options)

F.reset time
Auto reboot

6. Installing another country CSC or a network CSC will need the system partition size changing.
For this select Options and add this setting

Re-partition

NOTE:
1. You will get a WARNING from Odin.
You can ignore this.

2. If you are installing a multi csc firmware, and your existing CSC is in that firmware, then DO NOT select Re-partition.
You can check if your firmware is multi-csc by installing this app:
[https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.phoneinfo&hl=en]


3. To receive OTA updates, after installing the firmware, put phone into Recovery Mode to wipe cache then wipe data/factory reset.

A video guide here
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SK3IMprKVQ]
In the video guide the csc is not being changed and so Re-partition is not selected

Hope that helps."
```

Comment: I would suggest including a writeup in your answer just in case the link goes dead. A simple copy and paste as a block quote should suffice.

Comment: You are right. I will update the answer promptly. Thank you for notifying me.